# What are these called? --> %between%

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

Examples: `%random%`, `%username%`.

```
set /p test=.

echo %test%.
```

I want to look up all the different ones and I don't know what it's called.

Comment: environment variables? E.g. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Variables, which are located in an area of memory called the "operating system's environment".  Often these are called "environment variables".
Type `SET` to see what variables you have already set.
You can make up more, like running:
`SET ZSAMPLE=Y
ECHO %ZSAMPLE%
SET | FIND /I "ZSAMPLE"`

%RANDOM% is a special one.  EMK's comment referred to [ss64.com's page on variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) and that page mentions RANDOM and other "dynamic variables".  (Search that page for "dynamic" to see some more.)